# Jenkins Stop after found connection issue

Tags: maven, jenkins, jobs, slave

I have a problem with Jenkins, I have a Job with around 30 steps calling maven.
I have a slave machine running this job and the problem is that sometimes that slave machine disconnects and Jenkins stop working.
My question is, is any way to say Jenkins to continue with the next step in list in case of any connection error?
By the way I have think about to place each maven call in a separate job, but I would like to know if is possible what I am asking.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well if slave is disconnected then job has to fail :), what will you do with next step when your workspace is lost ??

Comment: The thing is that the Slave fails but you can run other job in it after failed.